# Why does Idris think my type parameter k is of type Type?

Tags: idris, idris2

Sorry I couldn't think of a less confusing way to put this.

I'm trying to build something like a map that can be safely accessed without returning a maybe, because all of its keys are contained in its type and querying for a key that isn't contained in its list of keys will throw a type error.

```
data SafeMap : (keys : List k) -> Type -> Type where
    Nil : SafeMap [] v
    (::) : Pair k v -> SafeMap ks v -> SafeMap (newKey :: ks) v

empty : SafeMap Nil v
empty = Nil

add : k -> v -> SafeMap ks v -> SafeMap (k :: ks) v
add k v l = (k,v) :: l

myDict : SafeMap ["test"] Nat
myDict = add "test" 234 Nil
--       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error here
```

The error message is

```
While processing right hand side of myDict. When unifying:
    SafeMap [?k] Nat
and:
    SafeMap [fromString "test"] Nat
Mismatch between: Type and String.
```

Why does it think that `?k` is of type `Type`?

By contrast, if I replace `k` with an explicit `String` everything works and there's no type error.

```
data SafeMap : (keys : List String) -> Type -> Type where
--                          ^^^^^^ changed here
    Nil : SafeMap [] v
    (::) : Pair k v -> SafeMap ks v -> SafeMap (newKey :: ks) v

empty : SafeMap Nil v
empty = Nil

add : (k : String) -> v -> SafeMap ks v -> SafeMap (k :: ks) v
--         ^^^^^^ and here
add k v l = (k,v) :: l


myDict : SafeMap ["test"] Nat
myDict = add "test" 234 Nil
-- No error here! ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
add : k -> v -> SafeMap ks v -> SafeMap (k :: ks) v
```

You want:

```
add : (k : _) -> v -> SafeMap ks v -> SafeMap (k :: ks) v
```

In `(v : t) ->`, `v` is the name of an argument of type `t`.

Comment: And what does my original code do? That I'm trying to cons a Type to a list of other Types?

Comment: Yes. Your original code would cons String to the list. This code would cons "test" to the list.

Comment: Ahh I'm with you. Thank you!